# Convert a float to a two-digit hex number in Python

Tags: python, hex

Unlike all the similarly worded questions on here, I'm not trying to get the actual hex value of the float. Basically I'm trying to make a gradient color and I need a function that looks like:

```
def float_to_color(weight):
    color = '#0000'
    hex = ????? #do something with weight here
    color += hex
    return color
```

The only way I can think of is to divide the `weight` float by 256 then have a different case that returns a different string for each the 256 "notches." There's gotta be an easier way!

Here's sort of what I need to make but instead of 10 different cases, I'd want every possible value 00 to FF to be represented proportional to 256 weight values. I can't use an RGB-tuple-type color because the specific module I need this for doesn't recognize it. The weight is an arbitrary 0.0-1.0 float value taken from a measurement. The color is supposed to represent it.

```
def weight_to_color(weight):
    color_base = '#0000'
    if weight > 0.9: return str(color_base+'FF')
    elif weight > 0.8: return str(color_base+'DD')
    elif weight > 0.7: return str(color_base+'EE')
    elif weight > 0.6: return str(color_base+'BB')
    elif weight > 0.5: return str(color_base+'99')
    elif weight > 0.4: return str(color_base+'77')
    elif weight > 0.3: return str(color_base+'55')
    elif weight > 0.2: return str(color_base+'33')
    elif weight > 0.1: return str(color_base+'11')
    else: return str(color_base+'00')
```

Comment: A color is 3 or 4 values. Where do you get them from?

Comment: What are the valid values of `weight`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
def int2hex(x):
    val = hex(x)[2:] # returns something like '0x15', so we remove the '0x'
    val = "0"+val if len(val)<2 else val # make sure 2 digits
    return val
```

Then in your function, you can get the hex value like

```
return color_base+int2hex(int(255*weight))
```

where `color_base ="#0000"`.

Looking at the *int2hex* function, we see

```
int2hex(int(255*0)) == "00"
int2hex(int(255*0.5)) == "7F"
int2hex(int(255*1.0)) == "FF"
```

This assumes that your weight runs from 0 to 1.  If it runs over a different range, you can use `int2hex(int(255*weight/max_weight))` where `max_weight` is the maximum allowed value.

Also, you shouldn't name a variable hex, because it will shadow the built in function hex.  This may be ok if you absolutely will not need that function in the same scope as the variable (in your case, you don't), but it is a poor habit to get into.

Comment: I don't think your answer addresses the question. The OP is asking about a floating point representation of color and converting it into an int value.

Comment: I don't think either of you quite understood what my problem is. I'll update the question.

Comment: @AustinCapobianco I've edited the answer for a weight between 0 and 1, but the previous version worked based on your extra info, other than assuming a float from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when a color is represented by a floating point value, it is in the range from 0.0 to 1.0. A weight of 1.0 corresponds to a hex representation of `0xff`. This means that you can **multiply** a floating point color value by `0xff` or its decimal equivalent **255**. You must also be sure to truncate the result to an int.